# How to Prevent GitLab Runner From Ever Using /home

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I build my runner and it works fine. However, when it initializes, it first clones the project to /home/user/builds/xxxx... I never, ever, ever want GitLab to use /home. Never. Not for anything. I was told that it is impossible to change it to a different location. I find it hard to believe.

See in the image below, it gives me a warning about templates not found in some made up directory, then clones the entire project under the user's home directory. I don't give it that command - so it must be a default. Is there a way to choose ANY other mount point? The project is several hundred gigabytes and the /home directory is 50k. I cannot control that. So to a different mount point it must go.

[image: Please make it stop]

I can provide the yml etc, but this is about core behavior of the runner itself - not anything I created. I'm hoping it is a simple variable I can send when initializing the runner.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can choose another option instead of using `ssh-runner` you can use docker runner!   However Try to take a look into this [link from Gitlab Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) It might help

Comment: They mentioned that you can configure the `builds_dir` properties based on what do you want, But I can't guarantee

Comment: ssh-runner is a child of docker-runner. I've looked at your suggestion and it seems like that would work. I'll try it out and report back any issues. Thanks for taking time to help me!